# Proof of Riemann integrability using zero set

Tags: real-analysis

The question is, if $f, g$ $\in$ $\mathcal{R}$ (are Riemann integrable) prove that $max(f, g)(x) = max(f(x), g(x))$ is also Rieman integrable.

I already know how to prove this, but I want to know why we can't simply conclude the set of discontinuity of $max(f, g)(x)$ is zero set, knowing that $f, g$ $\in$ $\mathcal{R}$, which results in having their set of discontinuity points being zero sets?

Comment: Of course, you can use this argument.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh! Nice! Because I was looking for validation for my proof and I didn't find anything like mine, I thought it might be wrong. Thank you.

Comment: One detail that seems potentially vexing is to show the discontinuity set of $\max(f, g)$ is contained in the union of the individual discontinuity sets. If one function or the other is larger on an interval there's no issue, but the graphs of $f$ and $g$ may cross infinitely many times in a closed interval, so one has to control this in studying continuity of $\max(f,g)$. <> By contrast, an argument based on the formula $\max(f, g) = \frac{1}{2}(f + g + |f - g|)$ makes clear there is no technical problem.